# Substract two datetimes and get seconds

Tags: php, datetime

I tried to substract two datetimes to get result by seconds like that:

```
$created = "2015-01-16 07:26:55";
$newdate_created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+2 month', strtotime($created)));
$now = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
$interval = date_diff($now, $newdate_created);
$seconds = $interval * 60 * 60 * 12 ;
```

But i'm getting this error:

> date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime
>   i dont know where is the problem to getting this working

I'm looking the output to be like that :

```
5259000   // something like that by seconds
```

Comment: `date()` does *not* create a DateTime object which is required to use `date_diff()`

Comment: Yeah if you were to stick with this code, it should be `$now = new DateTime();` and `$newdate_created = new DateTime('+2 month');`. Then your `$interval` will be a `DateInterval` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highly wasteful code. There is **NO** point in formatting your timestamps into strings, just to have to yank them back into timestamp format:

```
$newdate_created = strtotime('+2 month', strtotime($created));
$now = time();

$diff_in_seconds = $now - $newdate_created;
```

Comment: It really is that simple